# PostgreSQL - Create user and database from shell failing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, shell, root

I have a shell script which runs on deployment and I have these lines:

```
# Database
createdb $DBNAME
createuser -D -A $DBNAME
```

However, in my logs I get this error:

- createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident
  authentication failed for user "root"
- createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for
  user "root"

Would anyone mind telling me what is going wrong here and how I can correct my lines. Surely root should have permission to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best way to do this, especially if you want your script to be portable, is:

```
su --login postgres --command "createdb $DBNAME"
```

this should be safer, more secure, and more portable than using `-U`.  i do it this way in all my posgreSQL scripts.  you might find it a useful technique.  obviously it still needs to be run as a root user (e.g. with `sudo`).

Comment: I install postgreSQL with apt-get which makes a postgres account automatically. Is there any need to create a seperate user account like I did in my first post?

Comment: depends if you want a separate user for that db.  i nearly always do, since separation of privileges is usually a good idea :)

Answer (score 3):

If your DB is secured, you need to connect as a DB user, not as a user of the OS. For example:

```
createdb -U dbrootuser -W $DBNAME
```

See this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-createdb.html) for full syntax

Comment: I get this:
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/createdb: invalid option -- 'u'

Comment: My bad, case sensitive (should be U), have edited answer. Dbl check the link there if you have questions/ideas about the syntax.